# Reading in a file to create a 2d array word search puzzle and solve

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array, bufferedreader, filereader

Ok, so for this project I have a text file that is in the following format:

```
4 4
boba
cduf
engt
tach
aunt
bob
cat
```

The first line is designated to the dimensions of the word search puzzle. I create a 2d char array of that size to hold the puzzle. Then, I need to read each char from the next 4 rows, in this case, into my array. After that I must solve the puzzle by searching for any words that are below the puzzle I created, which in this case would be aunt, bob, and cat.

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.LinkedList;

public class WordPuzzleSolver {
    private char[][] puzzle;
    private String word;
    private LinkedList<String> words;
    private int index = 0;

    public void readFile(File inFile) {
        try{
            FileReader read = new FileReader(inFile);
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(read);
            String[] dimensions = reader.readLine().split(" ");

            puzzle = new char[Integer.parseInt(dimensions[0])][Integer.parseInt(dimensions[1])];

            for(int i = 0; i < puzzle[0].length; i++){
                String val = reader.readLine();
                puzzle[i] = val.toCharArray();
            }
            words = new LinkedList<String>();
            word = reader.readLine();
            while(word != null){
                words.add(word);
                word = reader.readLine();
            }

            while(index < words.size()){
                solvePuzzle();
                index++;
            }
            reader.close();
        }catch(IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void solvePuzzle() {
        char firstLetter = words.get(index).charAt(0);

        for(int i = 0; i < puzzle.length; i++){
            for(int j = 0; j < puzzle[i].length; j++){

                if(puzzle[i][j] == firstLetter){

                    if(checkUp(i, j, words.get(index))){
                        print(words.get(index), i, j, "U");

                        //System.out.println("the word found:"+word);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private boolean checkUp(int i, int j, String word){

        int index = j;
        for(char letter : word.toCharArray()){

            if(index >= puzzle[i].length){
                return false;
            }

            if(puzzle[i][index] != letter){
                return false;
            }

            index++;
        }
        return true;
    }
```

I'm doing something wrong with reading in my file, but i cannot figure out what. Because right now when i try to call `char firstLetter = word.charAt(0);` in my `solvePuzzle()` method i am getting a `NullPointerException`. That is my main problem but after i get that working I am unsure if my `checkUp` method is written correctly. I still have to write helper methods for the other 7 possible directions, but I wanted to use this one first on a text file where the only word to solve is in this direction.

Here is the current stack trace that I get:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 1, Size: 1
    at java.util.LinkedList.checkElementIndex(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.LinkedList.get(Unknown Source)
    at WordPuzzleSolver.solvePuzzle(WordPuzzleSolver.java:43)
    at WordPuzzle.solve(WordPuzzle.java:77)
    at WordPuzzle.actionPerformed(WordPuzzle.java:95)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

the last line that is called before the error is thrown is when i call char firstLetter = words.get(index).charAt(0);

Comment: Could you post the stacktrace, because from what I can see it's a bit odd that `char firstLetter = word.charAt(0);` gives a NullPointerException when you check `word` isn't null in the while-loop. (Also, I spotted one irrelevant mistake in your code: `for(int i = 0; i < puzzle[i].length - 1; i++){` should be `for(int i = 0; i < puzzle.length; i++){` (so `puzzle.length` instead of `puzzle[i].length`; and no `- 1` since you want indexes 0, 1, 2 and 3 (four words); instead of 0, 1 and 2.) This is irrelevant for your NullPointerException though..

Comment: I edited my code above to the code that was posted below with some minor changes along with the stack queue, as i am still receiving this error and cannot figure out why. I have been printing out my linked list of words to make sure that it is getting filled in with the appropriate words, which it has been, so i dont know why i am still getting null pointer exception.

Answer (score 1):

I have worked on your code.
Below is the working code

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class WordPuzzleSolver {
    private static  char[][] puzzle;
    public static String word;

    public static void readFile(File inFile) {
        try{
            FileReader read = new FileReader(inFile);
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(read);
            String[] dimensions = reader.readLine().split(" ");

            puzzle = new char[Integer.parseInt(dimensions[0])][Integer.parseInt(dimensions[1])];

            for(int i = 0; i < puzzle[0].length; i++){
                String val = reader.readLine();
                puzzle[i] = val.toCharArray();
            }
            word = reader.readLine();
            while(word != null){
                solvePuzzle();
                word = reader.readLine();
            }
            reader.close();
        }catch(IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void solvePuzzle() {
        char firstLetter = word.charAt(0);

        for(int i = 0; i < puzzle.length; i++){
            for(int j = 0; j < puzzle[i].length; j++){

                if(puzzle[i][j] == firstLetter){

                    if(checkUp(i, j, word)){
                        print(word, i, j, "U");

                        //System.out.println("the word found:"+word);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private static boolean checkUp(int i, int j, String word){

        int index = j;
        for(char letter : word.toCharArray()){

            if(index >= puzzle[i].length){
                return false;
            }

            if(puzzle[i][index] != letter){
                return false;
            }

            index++;
        }
        return true;
    }
```

Comment: This is working for me. Update if you not able to get the solution

Comment: Ok so i made these changes, and added some changes of my own. I cannot have static methods/variables in this program. I am still occuring the same error though. I added the stack queue as well along with where the line of code where the null pointer exception is thrown.

Comment: @DavidDoll. It's not a `NullPointerException`. It's a `IndexOutOfBoundsException`. And, yes, that's important.

Comment: @MadPhysicist woops that is what i meant to say. Anyway I dont get why I am getting that. In my test file I had only one word that I was searching for  which would have been set to the 0th index in the linked list, and my index variable gets initialized to 0.

Comment: @DavidDoll. #1, `int index = j;` is a really crappy thing to do. #2, You are not showing the complete code, so I suspect the error may be elsewhere.

Comment: @MadPhysicist  Yeah i figured out what was causing all of the errors. Everything is in working order, except for my checkUp method is not correctly checking for words in the up direction. Trying to figure that out now.